# How to open QDialog window instead of CloseWindow in taskbar

Tags: qt, qt5

How can I open a `QDialog` window instead QuitProgram in taskbar, when I click right-button in CloseWindow?

Check Image

[image]

Obs: I already have a QDialog UI with Button Quit Program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the `QWidget::closeEvent()` function in your main window. This is getting called when the user tries to quit the application. Example:

```
void YourMainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent* ev)
{
    QMessageBox msgBox(QMessageBox::Question,
                       tr("Quit"), tr("Are you sure you want to quit?"),
                       QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::Cancel);
    msgBox.setDefaultButton(QMessageBox::Cancel);
#ifdef Q_OS_MAC
    // This presents the dialog as a sheet in Mac OS.
    msgBox.setWindowModality(Qt::WindowModal);
#endif
    if (msgBox.exec() == QMessageBox::Yes) {
        ev->accept();
    } else {
        ev->ignore();
    }
}
```